# search a website in android

Tags: java, android, web

I am in a development of an android that will search for a particular word in a website..for that I developed some code...but it is not complete...is anyone able to help..it will be a help for me...thank you so much for reading

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et = new EditText(this);

     public void onClick(View v){
         Editable searchText = et.getText();
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.app.MainActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("searchQuery", searchText);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

Comment: explain more on website??

Comment: any websie for example....http://www.oxfamblogs.org/fp2p/?p=5672...and search for  a particular word 'tree' ...the app has to search on the above website and display the search results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it....

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:hint="Enter Your Text"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

EditText edt_search;

edt_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_search_book);
edt_search.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);

edt_search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
                   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                   KeyEvent event) {
                           // Log.i("KeyBoard" ,"Inside the Edit Text");
                           if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

                               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                               intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, edt_search.getText().toString()); // query contains                                                                                               
                               startActivity(intent); // search string

                           }
                           return false;
                   }
           });
```

Comment: but Chirag this will search for only text " android"...i thing there i have to change like intent.putExtra("query",ev.getText().toString());..

Comment: Please change your text with "android"

Comment: @user2223317 : what happen?

Comment: thanks chirag it is working...but i needed the user to give text...i already created an edit box...the user has to enter the text..and that text has to searcch in a website that i choose..now the text android is searching in google...instead the text has to search in an website i mentioned in the code....

Comment: btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
 {
  
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  
  {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Editable searchText = ev.getText();
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
   intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, ev.getText().toString()); // query contains                                                                                               
   startActivity(intent); 
  
   
  }
 });        I edited the code like this now the user can enter any word in text box and that word will be searched in google.

Comment: but i need to search inside this website http://www.oxfamblogs.org/fp2p/?p=5672  ... chirag can u please help me...

Comment: @user2223317 : I am trying if i get solution then give you.